# Exploring Apple Accessibility Audit in Xcode

Tags: swift, accessibility, xcode15, accessibility-api, accessibility-inspector

I'm exploring [Apple Accessibility Audit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accessibility/performing-accessibility-audits-for-your-app#All-platforms) in Xcode and can't figure out how an audit like elementDetection (XCUIAccessibilityAuditTypeElementDetection) works at all.

My goal is to build the elements so that AccessibilityAudit shows me a violation of this type (elementDetection).
Please, if anyone has received such a violation, tell us how you achieved it.

Thanks.

I created a custom button that has accessibility violations.
It has a UIAccessibilityCustomAction without a name, which logically should cause a violation of `elementDetection`.
I also tried to make elements invisible with a height of 0 by 0, elements that are off screen, but they `isAccessible = true`.

```
class ProductCardView: UIButton {
    private let productImageView = UIImageView()
    private let productNameLabel = UILabel()
    private let productPriceLabel = UILabel()
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setupViews()
        setupAccessibility()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func setupViews() {
        productImageView.image = UIImage(named: "exampleImage")
        productNameLabel.text = "Product Name"
        productPriceLabel.text = "$99.99"
        
        addSubview(productImageView)
        addSubview(productNameLabel)
        addSubview(productPriceLabel)
        
        productImageView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(200)
        }
        
        productNameLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(productImageView.snp.bottom).offset(8)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
        }
        
        productPriceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(productNameLabel.snp.bottom).offset(4)
            make.left.right.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(8)
        }
    }
    
    private func setupAccessibility() {
        isAccessibilityElement = false
        productNameLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
        productNameLabel.accessibilityLabel = nil
        let customAction = UIAccessibilityCustomAction(name: "", target: self, selector: #selector(handleCustomAction))
        accessibilityCustomActions = [customAction]
        
    }
    @objc private func handleCustomAction() -> Bool {
        print("Custom action performed.")
        return true
    }
}
```